# FB.login() not being called

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have my sdk set up and the button fires the `checkLoginState` function but the FB.login doesn't get called. I'm using the latest version (v2.9). I've also tried using 2.8.

I'm guessing it's something to do with it being async but I can't figure out what to do next.

The code:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      status : true, 
      cookie : true, 
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    }); 
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<fb:login-button onlogin="checkLoginState();" show-faces="false" scope="email,public_profile" width="400"></fb:login-button>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    function checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });
    }

    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        if (response.status !== 'connected'){
            Facebook_login();
        }
        else{
            console.log(response);
        }
      }

    function Facebook_login() {

        FB.login(function (response) {  <--- debugger comes here
            if (response.status === 'connected') { <----- but not here :-(
                //do stuff
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: What is `response` in `FB.login`? Try it with `==` rather than `===`.

Comment: @JayGould response is "unknown"

Comment: The login button performs the login on its own, you do not have to call FB.login yourself when you use that button. And the way you are caling it, inside the callback function of asynchronous methods, it will most likely get blocked by the browser’s popup blocker.

Comment: @CBroe if you want to create an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login button performs the login on its own, you do not have to call `FB.login` yourself when you use that button.

`FB.login` is for when you want to use *your own* link/button to trigger login.

---

And the way you are calling it, inside the callback function of asynchronous methods, it will most likely get blocked by the browser’s popup blocker. If you use `FB.login`, then you should only ever call it on directly user interaction (i.e., a click on a link/button), and not nest it into any async callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span><a onclick="fbLogin()" id="fbLink" class="btn faceebook btn-circle muliregular text-capitalize"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook </a></span>

var global_fb = false;

   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   // FB JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
   FB.init({
   appId      : 'xxxxxxxx', // FB App ID
   cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
   version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
   });

   // Check whether the user already logged in
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
   //display user data
   getFbUserData();
   }
   });
   };

   // Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
   (function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

   // Facebook login with JavaScript SDK
   function fbLogin() {
   global_fb = true;
   FB.login(function (response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
   // Get and display the user profile data
   getFbUserData();
   } else {

   }
   }, {scope: 'email'});
   }

   // Fetch the user profile data from facebook
   function getFbUserData(){
   FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture'},
   function (response) {
   $.post('loginwithfacebook',{userData:response},function(data){
   if(data.id != ""){
       if(global_fb == true){
           // do something 
       }
   }
   });
   });
   }
```